# Looking for references related to an inequality in order statistics

Tags: statistics, reference-request, normal-distribution, order-statistics

I was reading the paper ["on the minimum of several random variables"](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2006-134-12/S0002-9939-06-08453-X/S0002-9939-06-08453-X.pdf). In example 10 item (ii) it states:

Let $1\leq k\leq n$. Let $g_i,i\leq n$, be independent $N(0,1)$ Gaussian random variables. Then for $k\leq n/2$:
$$c\sqrt{\ln\frac{2n}{n+1-k}}\leq\mathbb{E}(k\text{-}\min_{i\leq n}|g_i|)\leq C\sqrt{\ln\frac{2n}{n+1-k}}$$
where $c,C$ are absolute constants.

The author claimed that this is a well-known inequality so he didn't provide the proof. I am interested whether this inequality has a name and how this was proved. Especially I am interested in the proof techniques, since recently I was working on a project related to this topic, I would like to see whether or not similar result can be generalized to other distributions( e.g. sub-gaussian).

Does anyone know any reference related to this? Thanks a lot.

A clarification:  The notation $(k\text{-}\min_{i\leq n}|g_i|)$ is used to mean "the $k$-th smallest value of $|g_i|$ over the set of $n$ variates." (mf)

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this question? Thanks.

Comment: I think this reference is helpful here: J.P. Royston. Expected Normal Order Statistics (Exact and Approximate): https://www.jstor.org/stable/2347982
Also, check this thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9001/approximate-order-statistics-for-normal-random-variables